# Regex Problem(C#)

Tags: c#, html, regex

HTML:

```
<TD style="DISPLAY: none">999999999</TD>
<TD class=CLS1 >Name</TD>
<TD class=BLACA>271229</TD>
<TD>220</TD>
<TD>343,23</TD>
<TD>23,0</TD>
<TD>222,00</TD>
<TD>33222,8</TD>
<TD class=blacl>0</TD>
<TD class=black>0</TD>
<TD>3433</TD>
<TD>40</TD>
```

I need td in value. How to do it in C#? I want a string array;

```
999999999
Name
271229
220
```

Comment: You should learn to pose your questions properly. With a sentence like "i need td in value how to make csharp, i wanna string array;" it is unlikely to get many answers, although Oded gave you already a good answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/

Answer (score 7):

Do not use regular expressions to parse html - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) for why.

Use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the HTML and extract the data in it.